Lots of prisoners were dumped onto a remote island to kill each other
I am looking for the title of a movie about a bunch of prisoners who were dumped onto a remote island by air using aircraft. They were on the island to make money on a reality show that people watch live on TV and internet. The island has lots of cameras to view the prisoners' movements.
Before the prisoners were dumped onto the island, each of them had a bomb and GPS attached to their foot with a trigger that would explode if the bomb was removed from their leg.
I only remember the scene a bit because I watched the movie when I was 12. It was a great movie because lot of the actors in it are from WWE entertainment such as Stone Cold Steve Austin. It has lots of action and revenge in the movie. 

Welcome! You say you saw it when you were 12 but that only helps us if we knew how old you are now. Please tell us what year you saw it in, rather than your age at the time.

"It was a great movie ..." - Not by any definition of the word.

The movie that you're referring to is The Condemned. The WWE wrestler that you're referring to would be Steve Austin.
From wikipedia:

The film was produced by WWE Studios (then WWE Films)
The film centers on ten convicts who are forced to fight each other to
  the death as part of an illegal game which is being broadcast to the
  public.
A bomb is placed on the ankle of every contestant, each featuring a
  30-hour countdown timer, and a pin (similar to a grenade) that will
  detonate the bomb after a ten-second delay.

From IMDB:

He is "purchased" by a wealthy television producer and taken to a
  desolate island where he must fight to the death against nine other
  condemned killers from all corners of the world, with freedom going to
  the sole survivor.

Check out the official trailer
